# Rails Routing with Constraint Class not working like expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a more complex constraints for routing, why is this simple example not working:

```
class FooBar
  def self.matches?(request)
    true
  end
end

get ':foo', to: redirect('/bar'), constraints: FooBar.new
```

All I get is

```
Invalid constraint: #<FooBar:0x007f87f14dce40> must respond to :call or :matches?
```

Any ideas how to get it work? Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to instantiate `FooBar` in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> must respond to :call or :matches?

Whats mean the instance of the FooBar must have a method(not the class method like in your code) `matches`:

```
class FooBar
  def matches?(request)
    true
  end
end
```

Or responde to `call`, `proc` in my example:

```
FooBar = proc do |request|
   # here goes code
end

get ':foo', to: redirect('/bar'), constraints: FooBar
```

Comment: Thanks! Works now. I will switch to proc.